# Proper use of MemoryCache with generics?

Tags: c#, generics, value-type, reference-type, memorycache

I wish to use `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` but I'm wondering how to use it with generics.

In the following example, I would be in trouble if `T` is a value type.

```
public T GetItem<T>(string key, Func<T> loadItemFromDb)
{
    var cachedItem = (T) memoryCache.Get(key);
    if(cachedItem != null)
       return cachedItem;

    // call db
    //put result in cache
    // return result
}
```

`MemoryCache.Get(string key)` returns `null` if the cache entry identified by `key` doesn't exist and it would raise `NullReferenceException` as it tries to do `(T)null` (with `T` a value type)

How could I get similar behaviour for every `T` ?

EDIT : I removed `where T : class` as this constraint prevents the case I'm describing.

EDIT 2 : I add some code to provide intent

Comment: `var item = memoryCache.Get(key) as T;`

Comment: @RonBeyer I thought `as` is for reference and nullable type only ?

Comment: Your `where T : class` makes `T` nullable, it can't be a value type, `class` is a reference type only.

Comment: Oh true. And if there were no constraint here ?

Comment: Then you need to check the type: `var item = memoryCache.Get(key); if (item is T) return (T)item; else return default(T);` Or something to that effect.

Comment: You ask "how can I get around this?" without saying what you want to happen.  You don't want to crash horribly I assume, but you haven't said what you want to happen. You call `GetItem<int>("foo")` and key foo doesn't exist, and... what happens?

Comment: @EricLippert Oh you are right. I add some code to provide intent. It works with a reference type, but would crash sadly with a value type. I'm trying to have a similar behaviour for every `T`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the cast can fail if the value is null. So **don't cast if the value is null**.

```
public T GetItem<T>(string key, Func<T> loadItemFromDb)
{
    object cachedItem = memoryCache.Get(key);
    if (cachedItem is T)
       return (T)cachedItem;
    T item = loadItemFromDb();
    memoryCache.Add(key, item, somePolicy);
    return item;
}
```

There's no problem with value types here; if T is a value type, and `cachedItem` is not a boxed `T`, then we never cast `cachedItem` to `T`.

FYI in C# 7 you can tighten that up a bit to:

```
    if (cachedItem is T t)
       return t;
```

and now there's no cast at all!

Answer (score 3):

Based on @ericlippart's answer, this looked like a good method to implement as an extension method and there are a couple of issues not addressed in his answer:

1. You need a cache policy to insert the result of loadItemFromDb function in the question which isn't passed into the function.
2. The Add method in Eric's answer doesn't exist (with that signature).

As `MemoryCache` is just an implementation of the abstract class `ObjectCache` and it does not use any `MemoryCache` specific functionallity, I based this on `ObjectCache`.

A full implementation of the Generic version of the `AddOrGetExisting` method on `ObjectCache`:

```
    public static T AddOrGetExisting<T>(ObjectCache cache, string key, Func<(T item, CacheItemPolicy policy)> addFunc)
    {
        object cachedItem = cache.Get(key);
        if (cachedItem is T t)
            return t;
        (T item, CacheItemPolicy policy) = addFunc();
        cache.Add(key, item, policy);
        return item;
    }
```

Note that this uses the C# 7 enhancement mentioned and also `System.ValueTuple` which is available from NuGet if using net461 or higher or is built into netstandard2.0

A full extension class, along with generic versions of Get and TryGetValue, as well as a number of other overloads of AddOrGetExisting is available in my GitHub repository [CZEMacLeod/ObjectCacheExtensions](https://github.com/CZEMacLeod/ObjectCacheExtensions/blob/master/src/ObjectCacheExtensions/ObjectCacheExtensions.cs)